# Laravel 5 return view by ajax - is my method hacky or good?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I've been learning Laravel and have worked through a series of tutorials on Youtube by Mindspace to build a social network. I've extended the basic site to include posts with images and video along with other things. During the process of this I changed the initial create post to be an ajax post of the data and wanted to update the feed but couldn't seem to find a way of doing return view by reading the docs (a little) and googling. However, I came up with this idea:

My ajax call sends the post and all the info over, postController.php stores them in the database and then the callback is a Laravel return view as shown here:

```
return redirect()->route('dashboard')->with(['message' => $message]);
```

This sends the whole page HTML back, which I thought I could use Jquery to do this:

```
$('body').html(msg);
```

It works like a charm and renders the whole page again, with the new post I made. I am wondering though, is this considered a "hacky" way of doing things? It does work brilliantly though...

Comment: That is a bit hacky, but you're on the right track. I would personally have the response be a JSON object with the new post data, and use that to append or prepend the new post to whatever container you'd like to add it to.

Comment: Oh yes I never thought of that. I'm mainly asking because I'd prefer to learn to write correct code than just anything that works.

Answer (score 1):

You may return a JSON response to your ajax request with (or without) a message, like this:

```
return Response::JSON(['status' => 'successful', 'foo' => 'bar']);
```

then, and in our success callback function, you may redirect the user to another page or view, like below:

```
$.ajax(  
..
success: function(data) {
  window.location.replace("anotherURL");
..
});
```